# What's wrong with my proof of the derivative of $e^x$ not being $e^x$?

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function

New here, and so this might be a foolish question. I have observed the exponential rule, and that is that the derivative of $n^x = n^x \cdot \log(n)$.

I'd like to know why this is true, and why my proof of the derivative of $\operatorname{e}^x = \operatorname{e}^x \cdot\log(\operatorname{e})$ is wrong.

Comment: your $\log$ is actually a natural logarithm. The result follows by definition of logarithm

Comment: Do you know what is the natural log of $e$ ?

Comment: Basic rule for log: logarithm in base $a$ of $a$ is $1$; log in base $b$ of $b$ is $1$; log in base $c$ of $c$ is $1$,...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, ah, thanks... I made a stupid mistake in my calculator, and did not specify a base...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof not really **wrong**, per se, since $$\frac{d}{dx}e^x = e^x\cdot \log(e)$$ **is** in fact true, as long as you realise that $\log$ is the natural logarithm, which means that $\log(e)=1$.

If you use a logarithm in any other base, say $a\neq e$, then the equality $$\frac{d}{dx} n^x = n^x\cdot \log_a(n)$$ is no longer  true, and *then*, your proof is indeed wrong.

Comment: Ah, my calculator was using logarithms of base 10 instead of the natural logarithm...

Answer (score 0):

The rule you are using applies only to natural logarithm. If $\log$ denotes natural logarithm then $\log e =1$.